# Stream youtube livestream through discord.js

Tags: typescript, discord.js, ytdl

I have been working on a custom discord bot, mostly for fun, but also for some friends. I want to stream a livestream (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5qap5aO4i9A) in a voice chat whenever anyone uses the `!play study` command. I am using ytdl-core-discord, but I keep getting the same error:

```
Error: Error parsing info: Unable to retrieve video metadata...
```

A lot of people online say that the way to solve this is simply to update ytdl, however I installed it today and am completely updated. Needless to say, this does not play any music to the voice channel, however it does join the channel.

foo.ts:

```
import {MessageEmbed, Message} from 'discord.js';
import config from '../../GGBot.config.js';
import ytdl from 'ytdl-core-discord';

export default async (msg: Message) => {
    if(!msg.member?.voice.channelID){
        msg.channel.send(
            new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor(config.embedColor)
            .setTitle('You Must Be In A Voice Channel To Play Audio')
            .setThumbnail(msg.author.displayAvatarURL())
            .setDescription('Please join a voice channel to play audio')
        )
        return;
    }

    const connection = await msg.member.voice.channel?.join();
    const stream = await ytdl('w2Ov5jzm3j8', {filter:'audioonly'});
    connection?.play(stream, {seek:0, volume:1})
        .on('finish', () => msg.member?.voice.channel?.leave());
    console.log('playing')
        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked into the docs and I don't think you can pass a ID to the `ytdl` function, you need to use a url. Something like this: `"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v= ${videoId}"`

edit: here is the link to the `ytdl-core` [docs](https://github.com/fent/node-ytdl-core#readme) since the `ytdl-core-discord` is just a wrapper

Comment: I've added it, thanks for the heads up @dskrvk

Answer (score 0):

just add the quality choose a number from 93 to 95 (it's working for me)

```
const connection = await msg.member.voice.channel?.join();
const stream = await ytdl('streamlink', {filter:'audioonly'}, {quality: '94'});
connection?.play(stream, {seek:0, volume:1})
.on('finish', () => msg.member?.voice.channel?.leave());
console.log('playing')
```